# Conditional check for response in Cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

[image]I need to put a condition that:
if the response body does not meet the criteria so, I need to

```
cy.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

But I do not know how to do it.[image]

Comment: What is the condition that you are looking to apply ?

Comment: My developer says it is better to see cy.log(JSON.stringify(res))response when the response does not meet the criteria. I asked if in the case of 404? he said not necessary. Only in case if the response does not meet the criteria

Comment: What is the criteria for this that you would be putting in if-else. Is it some response code or some response body data or response header or something else ?

Comment: response body. Added screen shot

Comment: So, basically he wants to see log
{"body":{"name":"VehicleNotFoundException","message":"Vehicle not found.",:"...}
in case of response body does not meet the criteria

Comment: So if the response code is 404 then you want to add the stringify statement ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238028/discussion-between-luna-and-alapan-das).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write something like:

```js
cy.request({
  body: {},
  failOnStatusCode: false,
}).then((res) => {
  if (res.status == 404) {
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(res.body)) //prints the response body
    cy.log(res.body.name) //prints name
    cy.log(res.body.message) //prints message
  } else {
    //Do Something else
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [fail event](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Catching-Test-Failures) to log your response if any criteria fails.

```js
cy.request({
  ...
})
.then(res => {

  Cypress.once('fail', (error, runnable) => {
    cy.log(JSON.stringify(res))
    throw error // throw error to have test still fail
  })

  expect(...
  expect(...
  expect(...
})
```